# assembly -- difference between `.text` and `.section __TEXT` on macOS?

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, llvm, sections

When writing assembly codes manually on macOS, `.section .text` will lead to "unexpected token in '.section' directive" error, and to fix is to remove `.section` token.

But when I generate assembly codes via clang like `clang xxxx.cpp -S`, it turns out something like

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
```

What is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're assembling your hand-written assembly with the same `clang`, right?  (And linking as well if you omit the `-c` option).

Comment: @PeterCordes I use GAS to assemble my hand-written assembly.

Comment: That's weird.  Normally `.text` is just an alias for `.section .text` at least on Linux systems with ELF object files.  Maybe MacOS uses different section names in its macho64 object file format, and `.text` becomes an alias for `.section __TEXT` with some attributes.  Anyway, clang has its own built-in assembler separate from GNU binutils `gas`.  They use the same syntax and directives, so they *should* be compatible.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think this is platform-related rather than assembler-related. I use GAS, g++ and clang to assemble the `.section .text` stuff, and all of them turn out "unexpected token in '.section' directive"; I use g++ and clang to generate assemble file from .cpp file, and both file include `.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions`

Comment: Yeah that was my assumption, too, that it's presumably normal for MacOS, not for one tool or the other.  [Disable assembler warning ".section \_\_TEXT,\_\_textcoal\_nt,coalesced,pure\_instructions"](//stackoverflow.com/q/38193043) shows some examples of that being generated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figure out. According to apple's doc [OS X Assembler Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000823-SW1), directive `.text` is section `(__TEXT,__text)`