# not sure how to fix this error - error: unexpected token in '.section' directive .section .text

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, x86-64

I bought a book called "learn to program with assembly" as a guide for learning assembly language. it said to download docker and run and create this file called "myexit.s" and copy in a small section of code.

I have copied the code verbatim from the page. it goes like this:

```
.globl _start

.section .text

_start:

    movq $60, %rax
    movq $3, %rdi
    syscall
```

so I typed it in correctly, but I am getting this error message :

myexit.s:1:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
....it points a green ^ to the space after the word text.

I have spent some time looking at forums for an answer, but nothing that worked or applied to me. help is appreciated.

by the way I am running docker, Mac Big Sur 11.2.3

Comment: Try `global` and `section` instead of `.globl` and `.section`

Comment: now it says :     myexit.s:1:1: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'global'
global _start
^~~~~~
myexit.s:3:1: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'section'
section .text
^~~~~~~

Comment: what is the name of the assembler?

Comment: I was trying to convert it from myexit.s to myexit.o in the command line (as myexit.s -o myexit.o) , which I opened through docker... sorry im new to assembly, and the book im reading just said to do it that only

Comment: If your assembler is the same as this one, `.globl` and `.section` seem to be fine. --> 
[Assembler Directives](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000823-SW1)
I'm not a user so I can't be sure, but you might try reversing the order of the `.globl` lines and the `.section` lines. Because all the sample code in the above page is like that.

Comment: that is another whole question I have I guess - the book says to download docker and once its running, type the following into the command prompt under a directory you want to use:  {Docker run -it —rm —mount “type=bind,src=`pwd`,target=/my-code”johnnyb61820/linux-assembly} its supposed to open up an image in docker but my command prompt just says : {invalid argument "“type=bind,src=/Users/hill,target=/my-code”johnnyb61820/linux-assembly" for "--mount" flag: unexpected key '“type' in '“type=bind'
See 'docker run --help'.}

Comment: sorry about the sloppy format above

Comment: That code is for Linux.  Same syntax, but wrong system-call number for MacOS.  `clang -nostdlib foo.s` on my Linux system makes a working statically-linked executable, so I can't reproduce the syntax error with clang's built-in assembler.  What clang version are you using?  Are you sure there aren't any non-ASCII characters?  Check with `hexdump -C foo.s` or something.

Comment: Oh, I may have figured it out. Replace `.section .text` with `.text`. See the .section directive section and the "Built-in Directives" section on the aforementioned pages for more information.

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko: Oh right, MacOS might use different section names.  Normally `.text` is just a shortcut for `.section .text`, but on MacOS it might be an alias for `.section something_else`, wherever MacOS compilers put machine code.  Ah yes, [assembly -- difference between \`.text\` and \`.section \_\_TEXT\` on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56919075) confirms it.

Comment: GREAT!! removing "section" worked!!! thanks everyone

Comment: next the book says to "link" the file... using: ld myexit.o -o myexit....now there is another error: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: im confused because the book said these lessons can be used with Mac

Comment: Are you using an M1 Mac? If so, try adding an option like `ld -arch arm64`. May be `aarch64` instead of `arm64`.